# Properly handle ModelView responses in MVC EF ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to models, say A and B

```
public class A
{
public int AID {get; set; }
public string Name {get; set;}
public virtual B B {get; set;}
}

public class A
{
[ForeignKey("A")]
public int BID {get; set; }
public string Name {get; set;}
public virtual A A {get; set;}
}
```

And a ViewModel

```
public class ABViewModel
{
public A A {get;set;}
public B B {get;set;}
}
```

Then I want a View, that allows me to set the names of both models simultaneously, so the controller looks something like

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
var viewModel = new ABViewModel();
return View(viewModel);
}
```

So far so good, how does the response look like? Something like the following returns an error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "A, B")] ABViewModel stuff)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.A.Add(stuff.A); // <-- here occurs the error
            stuff.B.A = stuff.A;
            db.B.Add(stuff.B);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(stuff);
    }
```

Comment: `"... returns an error"` - Perhaps the error is telling you what's failing?

Comment: You need to include what exception are you getting.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ViewModels this time.

Your `A` contains `B` and `B` contains `A`.

first. choose one of them, let me pick `A`

```
public ActionResult Create()    {
    var model = new A();
    model.B = new B();
    return View(model);
}
```

then you modify on the "view" the A content and the A.B content

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind] A stuff)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.A.Add(A);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(stuff);
}
```

once A contains B, there is no need to add B. The ModelState of B will be set to `ModelState.Added` also.

Answering your question. at the line: `db.A.Add(stuff.A);` `A` does not contains `B` instance initialized. `A.B` is null. That is why you're getting an error.

You must first add the `B` to the `A` and then save the db. If you really want to create a ViewModel, do the fallowing.:

```
stuff.A.B = stuff.B;
db.A.Add(stuff.A); // <-- Here is all good cause now A contains B.
stuff.B.A = stuff.A; // there is no need for it anymore
db.B.Add(stuff.B); // no need, B was already added on A.Add(...)
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ok, that worked thank you very much. But how about the setup as in the question, i.e. with ViewModel? I hesitate to accept this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this right now, but I don't think that works.... The error I get is a `null` at the line `db.A.Add(stuff.A)` because `stuff.A` is null.... how is your answer solving that, I don't see that.

Comment: Debug your app and see if `stuff` is correctly bound. If it's not your problem must be something else, like the view input or the bind itself.. Note that I removes A and B from bind filters.

Comment: It actually worked... but I think, it's better to just include `public string nameOfA` and `public string nameOfB` in the ViewModel and have some sort of mapping to the actual models.